# Best way to search specifics registers with Like SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm newer DB Learner and i have one specific question. I Have to search results on my database and only bring the data who have specific codes, and i made the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYDB 
WHERE C6_PRODUCT = 'OP78987' 
    AND C6_NOTE = '' 
    AND D_E_L_E_T_ = '' 
    AND C6_CF LIKE '%5106%' 
    OR C6_CF LIKE '%6106%' 
    OR C6_CF LIKE '%6108%' 
    OR C6_CF LIKE '%5108%' 
    OR C6_CF LIKE '%6403%'
```

The C6_CF have a lot of codes, but i only need a few of them (5106,6106,6108,5108,6403,5403,5933,6933,6912,5912,5908,6908)

When i run my query, with the Like, he brings the result only if i have 2 Likes, more of this, he bring all the database again.

There is a best way to do this? Any tips that i can search about ? (I made a search but i dont find anything by now, but im still searching!)

Comment: You probably want to use parenthesis around your logical `and` and `or`

Comment: A subquery could likely be easier here `... AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES('%5106%'),('%6106%'),...('%6403%'))V(Pattern) WHERE YT.C6_CF LIKE V.Pattern)`

Comment: What's the type of `C6_CF `? Using LIKE to search in the middle of a string is very slow. Searching for a string in the middle of a field can't use any indexes. If you want to search for exact values use `C6_CF  IN ('5106','6106',...)`. If `C6_CF` isn't a text field, don't use strings. Use numbers instead, `C6_CF  IN (5106,6106,...)`

Comment: As for `bring all the database again.` AND has higher precedence than OR in binary logic. The query you wrote is equivalent to `(C6_PRODUCT = 'OP78987' AND ... C6_CF LIKE '%5106%')` *OR* `(C6_CF LIKE '%6106%' )` *OR* `(C6_CF LIKE '%6108%').`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change your database tables, you would have to use your code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYDB 
WHERE
    C6_PRODUCT = 'OP78987' 
    AND C6_NOTE = '' 
    AND D_E_L_E_T_ = '' 
    AND
    (
        C6_CF LIKE '%5106%' 
        OR C6_CF LIKE '%6106%' 
        OR C6_CF LIKE '%6108%' 
        OR C6_CF LIKE '%5108%' 
        OR C6_CF LIKE '%6403%'
    )
```

But it is generally a bad idea to look after a part of varchar in a database.
If you can change your DB I would advice you to create a new table :

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    C6_PRODUCT VARCHAR(255), -- Put the right type
    C6_CF INT
)
GO
-- Create a FK between your tables for C6_PRODUCT
-- Create an index with C6_PRODUCT and C6_CF
```

Populate your table like so :

| C6_PRODUCT | C6_CF |
| --- | --- |
| OP78987 | 6106 |
| OP78987 | 6108 |
| AB78987 | 6106 |
| ... | ... |

Then you could have a powerfull query like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.C6_PRODUCT
FROM MYDB T1
INNER JOIN yourTable T2 ON T2.C6_PRODUCT = T1.C6_PRODUCT
WHERE T2.C6_CF IN (6106,6108,5108,6403)
    AND T1.C6_PRODUCT = 'OP78987' 
    AND T1.C6_NOTE = '' 
    AND T1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '';
```